# Unit Testing typescript-react with complicated props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a component with rather complicated Prop typing. All is good until I need to write unit tests, where it seems like I have to re-implement some of the most complicated logics just to pass the type checking. How should I write a simple mock? Is there a better way of handling typescript here? Thanks!

```
type Updater = (params: UpdaterParams) => void;
interface Props {
  // 20 props here

  getFieldUpdater: (params: GetFieldUpdater) => Updater;
}

class MyComp extends React.Component<Props> {
  foo() {
    const bar = this.props.getFieldUpdater(abc);
    // ...
  }
}

// MyComp.test.tsx
const mockProps = {
  // 20 mock props here
  getFieldUpdater: ???
}
it('foobar', () => {
  const mockComp = enzyme.shallow(<MyComp {...mockProps} />);  // Hard to pass the checks here
});
```

Comment: If you want to get lazy, you could use `Any-type` as `const mockProps: any = {...` declaration which allows `mockProps` to consist any values and doesn't typecheck on them. Use it sparely tho' since this makes typescript much less useful. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html you could research this more in here.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, this really makes things much easier!